# How do I turn off Avast AV entirely, without uninstalling it?

Tags: firefox, anti-virus

Just tried Firefox Dev and everything returns invalid certificate issues.  One possible cited cause are AV software, so I'd like to suspend Avast and see if it clears up.

Suspend/stop - not "turn off shields", that doesn't do much - Avast is still on the menu bar and still shows up on `pgrep`.  At the end of the day, I don't really care about live shields anyway - more interested in scanning downloads and the like.

I guess I could look at system services and turn Avast off there, but is there no way to tell the app to shut down?  Unusual to have such a badly behaved app on Macs.

edit:  all the `launchctl` fu I tried to apply didn't work and it even re-appeared after a reboot.  I think I'll have to de-install it if I want to truly stop it.  Not helping my trust either with a spammy "your system is wasting x GB storage, do you want to fix it?" popup of theirs.

As far as Avast + Firefox Dev edition goes, looking at [Connection is Untrusted](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1055902), I saw that the user uninstalled and reinstalled to accept the Avast cert.

So... I:

1. went to regular FF preferences searched for 'certificates' and exported the Avast cert.
2. went to FF dev version and imported the cert I had just exported. Its trust only needs to identify websites.

FF Dev works now.

<s>Still not sure I will keep Avast around.</s>

Uninstalled, this whole "can't be paused or disabled" is arrogant and annoying, especially as the main reason for wanting it was on-demand scanning of downloads, not constant running.

Comment: AVs don't like things trying to switch them off... that's part of their job. See if it has a whitelist option somewhere [idk Avast specifically]

Comment: Yes, I know.  On the other hand, AVs have some pretty poor security practices themselves because they can be used to hijack systems themselves.  I am sitting on the fence on keeping Avast around - it's not the first time I've de-installed Mac AVs, they hardly seem worth the hassle and it's not like they are in any way really battle-tested, unlike on Windows.  So "it's their job" clashes with "I'm in control of my machine" here.

Comment: i have to agree; & Avast particularly is known to be very heavy on the system. I could even feel its impact on a dual 6-core Xeon Mac Pro. I go through phases of "must have an AV/gotta get rid of this AV", right now in the 'get rid' phase, last one to go was BitDefender... they just get in the way :/